# Bing/Google Search or URL suggestion feature , implement search provider

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make edit box which can provide URL/Search keyword suggestion when use type it. Do you guys have any idea where should I start ? I've review the BING API but I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 0):

For your edit box I'd recommend using the `AutoCompleteBox` from the [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034).

Google has a [custom serch API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) which may be a good place to start looking for a data source for your searches.